# Skyrim Purchased Horses

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps4

I bought every horse from every stable (I like the color changes from time to time). Then my horses from Markarth and Whiterun died. Now when I go back to those two stables and ask the stable master to buy another, he tells me "I just sold my last one, pretty sure it was to you." That was like, a month ago in both real and Skyrim time.

Can you really only purchase one horse from each stable the entire game?

Anyone have any ideas how to get new horses at the stables to be purchased?

Answer (score 3):

> **Purchasing a new horse after it dies**
>   Some horses in Skyrim will spawn at a Hold's stable after waiting some time at a different location. It will usually take 1 to 2 days for a horse to spawn and be available for purchase after one of the horses at the stable dies. The time for a new horse to spawn for purchase depends on the actions at the stable, for example, if the player returns to the stable at which the old horse was bought, and steals an unsaddled horse before waiting a day and killing it, it will take at least one extra day waiting in game for a new horse to spawn for purchase. The original horse will re-spawn in about 10 days waiting in-game, making 1 or more horses available for purchase at a Hold's stable. It is also possible, after the previous horse dies, for a new saddled horse to spawn at a stable. Allowing it to be purchased for 1,000 gold, and still making it so the old horse will re-spawn without having to repurchase it. This will make it so that 1 or more horses can be owned at a stable at once.
>
> **Horses that re-spawn after they die**
>   Horses that will be able for purchase after the previous one dies are at
>
> Markarth Stables – Wait one day in game, then return to the stables. At least one horse should be available to be purchased by the Dragonborn. Old horse will re-spawn.
>
> Whiterun Stables – Wait one day in game, then return to the stables. At least one horse should be available to be purchased by the Dragonborn. Old horse will re-spawn.
>
> Windhelm Stables – Wait one day in game, then return to the stables. At least one horse should be available to be purchased by the Dragonborn. Old horse will re-spawn.
>
> Riften Stables – Wait one day in game, then return to the stables. At least one horse should be available to be purchased by the Dragonborn. Old horse will re-spawn. Old horse will not re-spawn.
>
> Katla's Farm – Wait one day in game, then return to the stables. At least one horse should be available to be purchased by the Dragonborn. Old horse will re-spawn. New horse will not spawn for purchase, however the Dragoborn's old horse should re-spawn after waiting 10 days in game at a different location.

All from [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Horse_(Skyrim))